# Splitting GeoTIFF into tiles in QGIS NextGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, nextgis

There is a GeoTIFF of around 3.5 Gb. I would like to get 6 sliced jpg tiles from it (width is one second of the original file, and hight is one third) with JGW bindings.

How is it possible to implement in QIGS?

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing as follow:

1. Get raster's spatial extension (for example going to Information tab of Raster Layer Properties dialog). [image: Raster Layer Properties dialog: xmin,ymin,xmax,xmax raster's coordinates]

2. In Raster-->Extraction menu run "Clip raster by extent" tool  selecting the raster you want to clip and choosing as extension parameters the following:

xmin=xmin_orig_raster+ m *(xmax_orig_raster-xmin_orig_raster)/2 (m going from 0 to 1)
xmax=xmin_orig_raster + (m+1)*(xmax_orig_raster-xmin_orig_raster)/2 (m going from 0 to 1)
ymin=ymin_orig_raster + n*(ymax_orig_raster-ymin_orig_raster)/3 (n going from 0 to 2)
ymax=ymin_orig_raster + (n+1)*(ymax_orig_raster-ymin_orig_raster)/3 (n going from 0 to 2)

Running the tool 6 times, each with the appropriate parameters (depending on the slice you're slicing) should give you the wanted result.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Unfortunately I can't open properties window - QGIS is not responding for a long time. I think this is due to the large file size. May be I can solve my task with some command line app?

Comment: You can get the raster spatial extension by running raster infromation in raster-->miscellaneous menu. Don't need to load the raster into the project. It should give you the spatial extension infos in seconds .

Comment: edit - ...In the tool dialog leave all the flags unflagged (you don't need those) to speed up the processing.